# how to print array in javascript that has element pushed to it asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, async-await, jasmine, protractor, ui-testing

I am working on an end-to-end UI test cases using the protractor for non-angular application. I have a bunch of LI tags inside UL tag that is rendered on a webpage. and I need to get the value of all LI tags and store them in an array and then check if that array is sorted or not.

```
checkResultList() {
        // element locator for UL
        const listResult = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="flightModuleList"]'));
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(this.listResult), 60000);

        // Get All the LIs as ElementArrayFinder
        let items = listResult.all(by.xpath('//li//div[@class="uitk-col all-col-shrink"]//div[contains(@class,"primary-content")]//span[contains(@class, "full-bold")]'));

        let prices = [];
        items.each(function(ele, index) {
            ele.getText().then(function(text) {

                // get floating point numbers from string
                const price = text.match(/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g).map(function(v) {

                    prices.push(parseFloat(v));
                    return parseFloat(v);
                });

            })
        })

        expect(prices.length).toBe(80); // prints 0

    }
```

I expect prices array to have all the value pushed before I check it's length.

Comment: https://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await   ???

Comment: Why not use ```setInterval``` until length is as expected?

Comment: @Janak Please note that you have set ```let prices = [];``` twice! The first is redundant

Comment: @Mulli Because polling with `setInterval` is a horrible idea when you can just use promises

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that could give you some inspiration. The code below first awaits the item text and then gets any numbers from the text. It then waits for all items to resolve, before flattening the array (using `reduce`) by one level.

```js
// mock for items
class Item {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  
  getText() {
    return Promise.resolve(this.value);
  }
}

let items = ["foo", "bar +12.54", "baz -1.29", "1.23 4.56"]
  .map(str => new Item(str));

// answer
(async function () {
  let prices = items.map(async item => {
    let text = await item.getText();
    let prices = text.match(/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g) || [];
    return prices.map(parseFloat);
  });
  
  prices = await Promise.all(prices);
  prices = prices.reduce((acc, arr) => acc.concat(arr));

  console.log(prices);
})();
```

Alternatively you could simplify this further by awaiting all the results first. However since the regex matching and float parsing is independent for each item I've chosen **not** to do this. The code above will match the regex against the string as soon as the promise resolves instead of waiting for all promises to resolve and then match every element against the regex (as shown below).

The code (more compact, less optimal) for this would be:

```
(async function () {
  let texts = await Promise.all(items.map(item => item.getText()));
  let prices = texts
    .map(text => text.match(/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g) || [])
    .reduce((acc, arr) => acc.concat(arr))
    .map(parseFloat);
  console.log(prices);
})();
```